# How to tell browser that the form was wrong and do not save password

Tags: html, django

I have a website with a login form.
My problem is that every time this form is submitted, chrome suggests to save the password, **even if it's incorrect**

The form:

```
<form method="POST" action="" id='sign-in'>
  {% csrf_token %}
        
  <div class="form-group inner-addon">
    <input name="txt_login_username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
    <i class="fa fa-user fa-lg fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group inner-addon">
    <input name="txt_login_pass" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
    <i class="fa fa-key fa-lg fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>

  {% for message in messages %}
  <p class='alert alert-danger'>{{ message }}</p>
  {% endfor %}

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btn_login">Log In</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I believe Chrome only does that when the server responds with a success response code. If you respond with a `400 Bad Request` HTTP code instead, it shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out with the help of @deceze.
just need to add state=400 to the render method:

```
render(request, 'index.html', context, status=400)
```